# link_to and other view helpers not included with EJS (bundled with Express) for Node.js?

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I've set up a nodeJS server using the Express web framework, using the EJS template engine.

When I try to use the EJS `link_to` view helper inside a view, I get a reference error. Is this because I am doing something wrong, or are the view helpers just not included?

I've tried the following

```
<# link_to("...", "...") #>

<#= link_to("...", "...") #>

<#- link_to("...", "...") #>
```

*Note: I've configured custom tags for EJS...*

```
server.configure(function ()
{
    this.set("view engine", "ejs");
    this.set("view options", { open: "<#", close: "#>" });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

try :

```
var helpers = require('express-helpers')
```

and then

```
helpers(app);
```

in your app.js
if still not working, try 
`<%- link_to` instead of `<%= link_to`

Comment: Needed to install 'express-helpers' by npm install express-helpers. <%= not worked but <%- worked

Answer (score 2):

Add https://github.com/mhayashi/express-helpers , that should solve the problem..

Had some problems with their : require('express-helpers').all function though, rolled my own.
Besides that it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @user-S and @mujaffars
Just to write all the steps in one place,

1. Install express-helpers.

> `npm install --save express-helpers`

2. In app.js, write

> ```
> var expressHelpers = require('express-helpers');expressHelpers(app);
> ```

3. Use it in ejs in this way,

> 

Using <%= instead of <%- just displays the generated html anchor tag which is not we usually want.