# Ejs input_field_tag method setting type attribute as 5

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I am using ejs for template rendering, I am using below code

```
<%- input_field_tag('empName', 5) %>
```

Which generates output as

```
<input id="empName" value="" type="5" name="empName">
```

Here the `type` attribute is set as `5` -- Which actually need to be set as `text` and `value` attribute need to be set as `5`

I am referring code from [ejs_wiki_ViewHelpers](https://code.google.com/p/embeddedjavascript/wiki/ViewHelpers#input_field_tag), Where they stating that output will be generated as `<input id='empName' value='5' type='text' name='empName'/>`

Let me know what is going wrong in my code, because I have simply copy pasted it from the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably using [`express-helpers`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-helpers) module which uses different arguments than plain ejs view helpers.

The `input_field_tag` in express-helpers module takes `name` as the first argument, `inputType` as the second one and third is options object.

See [wiki](https://github.com/tanema/express-helpers/wiki) of this module for more information.

Comment: Yes I am using express-helpers module. And got your answer. But I am not seeing 'input_field_tag' method listed in provided reference link.

Comment: @mujaffars: Well it isn't in this list, but you can see source code of it. And like I told you before use `text_field_tag` for text inputs.

Comment: You caught me for 2 questions :)

Comment: @mujaffars: They are different questions. And you never told that you are using express-helpers module and not plain ejs view helpers. I figured that out only after your second question. ;)

Comment: While working on nodejs project with installing ejs the template was not rendering. I have followed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5553554/link-to-and-other-view-helpers-not-included-with-ejs-bundled-with-express-for and installed express-helpers. After that I can able to use ejs. Sorry I forgot to mention it in question.